# Create foreign key with if statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table with with an object id column and a type column.

I want to be able to be able to have ON DELETE CASCADE fk to reference different tables depending on the type.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a trigger on the table where the data you want to check to accomplish the deletion "ON CASCADE" and make the deletion there, otherwise is not possible to have the `ON CASCADE` with a condition.